# wordpress registration with payment option

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a website using wordpress where I want the users to register and pay monthly

subscription fees using paypal.

I want to allot them a specific role so that they can create post.

Now, if the user cancels its subscription through paypal how do I deactivate users membership automatically. 
Is there a way to get a notification from paypal to my wordpress site so that I can check

that and trigger the inactivation process.

please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need intergrate paypal using paypal API https://developer.paypal.com/
2. You can manage every role using this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/